# Workout buddy deadlifts 1200?

Tags: strength, stronglifts, deadlifts, lower-back, powerlifting

So recently my old workout buddy moved due to work and I have a new one now, mid 20s in good shape and strength. The only problem, which is a big one, is that I suspect him of lying. He has been boasting to the other people at the gym and to me that he can pull off a 1200 pound deadlift. I should also state he claims he can lift 700 in standing military press. However, he refuses to show any of us his extraordinary lifts like these he talks about(not saying he doesn't deadlift or military press just not that much) claiming he doesn't want attention. However, my theory is he is lying and just is trying to get attention by looking overly strong. Is what he's saying possible? Is it wrong to suspect my friend like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has ***little to do with fitness and the OP simply wants to prove that his friend is lying.***

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlift#World_records

Comment: Same for me. I can squat 5,000lb but just don't want all the attention so I stick with 225.

Comment: I'd squat my max, but I'd fall through the floor, and push Earth out of orbit.

Answer (score 4):

A 1200 pound deadlift would be a world record in any category (raw/equipped etc), so yeah he's lying. There doesn't seem to be a world record in standing military press, but the highest numbers I'm finding is around 500 pounds.